# i getting an error while sorting numbers

Tags: java, java-stream

I am getting an error while sorting numbers and  here is my code.
I have commented above the line where I get the error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class SortNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            int length = scanner.nextInt();

            List<Integer> inputList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                inputList.add(scanner.nextInt());

            }
            //I get error on this line help me to get it out  
            List<Integer> outputList = inputList.stream().sorted().collect();


            System.out.println(outputList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to close the `try` with a `}`.

Comment: add more details and full code .

Comment: okay i will give complete code

Comment: give us the error! What should be the output, what do you get? Smallest working example.

Comment: I want to Sort the  numbers in ascending order .. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either ways Collections.sort(list) or using streams

```
List<Integer> outputList = inputList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You might have facing the error because any of these two reasons

1. There won't be try block with neither catch or finally block
2. Compile Error in stream code instruction

   ```
   List<Integer> outputList = inputList.stream().sorted().collect(); //compile error as collect() method expects a parameter.
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Collection.sort(inputList);`

Stream isn't necessary.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11142194)

Comment: @blackbuild, disagreed. This answer provides a way to change the problematic line of code to make it working correctly. Even more, this solution is shorter and significantly more efficient than accepted one. Looks like a valid answer to me.